# Placing elements using CSS position-absolute

Tags: html, css

> I'am triyng to make Link A,B goes inside to Left element (green box), and Link C,D goes inside to Right element (yellow box), wrapped by container.
>   As the picture show, also i managed placing Link C,D on the right side using CSS `position: absolute;` `right: 0;`
>   but when i using `position: absolute;` `left: 0;`for Link A,B this link is not on the left side aligned to upper elements

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkvSH.png)

this is my code:

```html
<head>    
        <style>
          
            .container {
                width: 1000px;
                border: 3px solid black;
                margin: auto;
                padding: 16px;
                
            }
    
            .left, .right { width: 400px; }
    
    
            .left {
                background-color: #197b30;
                float: left;   
                color: white;
                font-style: italic;
                text-align: left;
                position: relative;
                 
                                                       
            }
    
            .left span {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: large;
                font-style: normal;
                text-decoration-line: underline;
                   
            }
    
            .left ul {
                color: rgb(243, 9, 126); 
                list-style-type: disc;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                
            }
    
            .left a { color: #ff0000}
    
            .right a { color: #ff0000}
    
    
            .right {
                background-color: #fff200;
                float: right;  
                color: black;
                font-style: italic;
                text-align: right;
                position: relative;
                                                 
                 
            }
    
            .right span {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: large;
                font-style: normal;
                text-decoration-line: underline;
                
            }
    
            .right ul {             
                color: rgb(243, 9, 126); 
                list-style-type: disc;
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                                  
            }      
       
            .clear {
                clear: both;
            }
                  
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
            <div class="container">
                <div class="left">
                    <p><span>This is a left paragraph</span</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel, aperiam odit 
                    nostrum, 
                    reprehenderit temporibus reiciendis aliquam maxime sunt qui quos eligendi sequi unde, 
                    quas molestiae explicabo quod harum veniam alias.</p>
                    
                    <p><span>This is a left link</span></p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Left Link A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Left Link B</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
                 
                <div class="right">
                    <p><span>This is a right paragraph</span></p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi incidunt 
                       necessitatibus adipisci eum harum, culpa, amet voluptate cumque molestias quos 
                       earum 
                       asperiores hic debitis iure iste porro? Fugit, itaque quo.</p>
                    
                    <p><span>This is a right link</span></p>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Right Link C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Right Link D</a></li>
                    </ul>
                     
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                          
           </div>
```

Comment: Can you please upload your solution to codepen?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `ul` element there's a default padding on the left hand side of every `li` element.

Try this:

```css
.left ul {
  color: rgb(243, 9, 126); 
  list-style-type: disc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;

  padding: 0;    /* Add this */       
}
```

That removes the padding and will position the navigation as you expect.

Comment: I followed your instructions, it works. thanks, But i still don't know how to place a Links into a green and yellow box ( Left and Right elements )